# Can we use 'take off' with the bottle cap?

Tags: meaning

is  it correct, if I use 'take off the bottle cap' meaning as unstop the bottle cap'?

thank you so much :)

Comment: Why would it not be correct?  "Remove" would be a bit more common, but "take off" is perfectly proper and doesn't sound especially strange.

Comment: If it is a bottle cap, you ***un***cap it. Sometimes remove it. Sometimes take it off. Sometimes get rid of it.

Comment: But if it is a cork you *uncork the bottle* or *remove the cork*. If it is a screw-cap you *unscrew* it.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use "take off" for clothes

Comment: We also use "take off" for air plane

Comment: And for discount on the price of a purchase.  And dozens of other things.  "Disrobe" would be relatively unique to clothes.